# JavaFX SceneBuilder 2.0 is not working on NetBeans

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, javafx, interface, scenebuilder

I am trying to integrate SceneBuilder into JavaFX in NetBeans. It doesn't seem to be showing:

[image]

[image: I HAVE ATTACHED HOW IT LOOKS LIKE IN THE IDE]

Answer (score 1):

use that [Scene Buider](http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/) once developed by Oracle and in the meantime significantly improved by Gluon, is currently available in version 8.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Download Scene Builder from http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/
and install it with the default location.

> **The default location for Scene Bilder is** : `C:\Users\{Your User Name}\AppData\Local\SceneBuilder`

Take this path , put your correct user name first, and paste it in the field `Scene Builder Home` in your picture.